# android: dagger - DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, dagger

[image: Can not resolve symbol DaggerAppComponenent]

Есть проект, написанный с использованием Dagger, по какой-то причине не видит DaggerAppComponenent, что. это может быть?

Comment: Нужно собрать проект, чтобы он появился

Comment: @IR42 действительно, проект не собирается, там есть неизвестная константа, которая не наю откуда берется

Comment: `   @ActivityScope|
    @ContributesAndroidInjector|
    abstract MainActivity_ contributesMainActivity();`